# Text field value to ProprtyType with Reactive Cocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to map text field content into ProprtyType. I have property in view model:

```
var property = MutableProperty<Int?> (nil)
```

And I wanted to bind it in `viewDidLoad`

```
let producer = textField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer().map { text in Int(text as! String) }
viewModel.property <~ producer
```

but I get error which I don't understand:

> Binary operator '<~' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MutableProperty' (aka 'MutableProperty>') and 'SignalProducer' (aka 'SignalProducer, NSError>')

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the bind operator <~ requires the error type of the signal producer must be `NoError`. So catch any error using flatMapError:

```
let producer = textField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
    .flatMapError { error in
        return SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NoError>.empty
    }
    .map { text in Int(text as! String) }

property <~ producer
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Now I understand.